# Problems with save() methof of django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, save

[image: console]
[image: my save method]

My prints are cycling and then the error message appears
But download_url which appears in the console seems to be correct and it works for me, but why code doesn't work
It's like a recursion in save method till Yandex block my downloads with "Resource not found"

```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # Сначала сохраняем объект

    if self.photo_url:
        base_url = 'https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/public/resources/download?'
        public_key = 'https://disk.yandex.ru/i/EaosKvCf-SDzag' #self.photo_url  # Используем поле photo_url как public_key

        final_url = base_url + urlencode(dict(public_key=public_key))
        print(final_url)
        response = requests.get(final_url)
        print(response.json())
        download_url = response.json()['href']
        print(download_url)

        download_response = requests.get(download_url)
        file_content = download_response.content

        file_name = self.photo_url.split('/')[-1]
        temp_file = File(io.BytesIO(file_content), name=file_name)
        self.photo.save(file_name, temp_file, save=False)
        self.save()  # Сохраняем с обновл

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is unrelated to Django and the save() method, as the error is caused by the external API, not Python itself.

If something works in your browser but not in Python `requests`, it means the host is filtering your bot. You have to emulate accessing like a real person.

To do so, open your browser, press F12, open the "Network" tab, load your URL, right click the first request, and select "Copy as cURL (bash)".

You can then use something like https://curlconverter.com/ to convert this into Python, and you'll see there are a lot of headers and cookies you're likely missing in your code.

The code you generate this way is (for most intents and purposes) the same as a request made from the browser.

[image]